# Intellij IDEA14 StackOverflow exception when I click Find Usage(or Alt+F7) on large memory PC

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I'm on Windows 7 PC with 32G memory and Intel i5 3.3GHz CPU and 512G SSD disk, however when I click Find Usage IDEA always give me stackoverflow exception, no matter how I reconfig the vm parameters.

Below is IDEA startup log:

`2014-12-11 10:53:22,633 [     27]   INFO -        #com.intellij.idea.Main - IDE: IntelliJ IDEA (build #IU-139.659.2, 06 Dec 2014 00:00) 
2014-12-11 10:53:22,633 [     27]   INFO -        #com.intellij.idea.Main - OS: Windows 7 (6.1, amd64) 
2014-12-11 10:53:22,633 [     27]   INFO -        #com.intellij.idea.Main - JRE: 1.8.0_20-b26 (Oracle Corporation) 
2014-12-11 10:53:22,633 [     27]   INFO -        #com.intellij.idea.Main - JVM: 25.20-b23 (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM) 
2014-12-11 10:53:22,634 [     28]   INFO -        #com.intellij.idea.Main - JVM Args: -Xms128m -Xmx750m -XX:MaxPermSize=1024m -XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=512m -ea -Dsun.io.useCanonCaches=false -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Djsse.enableSNIExtension=false -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:SoftRefLRUPolicyMSPerMB=50 -Xbootclasspath/a:C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 14.0.2\lib\boot.jar -Didea.paths.selector=IntelliJIdea14 
2014-12-11 10:53:22,688 [     82]   INFO -        #com.intellij.idea.Main - JNA library loaded (64-bit) in 53 ms 
2014-12-11 10:53:22,689 [     83]   INFO - penapi.util.io.win32.IdeaWin32 - Native filesystem for Windows is operational 
2014-12-11 10:53:22,690 [     84]   INFO -        #com.intellij.idea.Main - Using "FocusKiller" library to prevent focus stealing.`

And below is the exception(more than 1000 lines stack trace) when I press Alt+F7, please help, Thanks.

java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at com.intellij.util.containers.ConcurrentHashMap.computeHashCode(ConcurrentHashMap.java:3821)
    at com.intellij.util.containers.ConcurrentHashMap.hash(ConcurrentHashMap.java:3837)
    at com.intellij.util.containers.ConcurrentHashMap.get(ConcurrentHashMap.java:939)
    at com.intellij.util.containers.ConcurrentRefValueHashMap.get(ConcurrentRefValueHashMap.java:79)
    at com.intellij.util.containers.ConcurrentWeakValueHashMap.get(ConcurrentWeakValueHashMap.java:32)
    at com.intellij.psi.impl.file.impl.FileManagerImpl.findCachedViewProvider(FileManagerImpl.java:183)
    at com.intellij.psi.impl.file.impl.FileManagerImpl.findViewProvider(FileManagerImpl.java:171)
    at com.intellij.psi.impl.PsiManagerImpl.findViewProvider(PsiManagerImpl.java:190)
    at com.intellij.psi.impl.source.PsiFileImpl.isPsiUpToDate(PsiFileImpl.java:167)
    at com.intellij.psi.impl.source.PsiFileImpl.isValid(PsiFileImpl.java:163)
    at com.intellij.psi.impl.source.tree.SharedImplUtil.isValid(SharedImplUtil.java:78)
    at com.intellij.psi.impl.source.tree.CompositePsiElement.isValid(CompositePsiElement.java:128)
    at com.intellij.lang.javascript.frameworks.mozilla.XulLanguageInjector.getLanguagesToInject(XulLanguageInjector.java:42)
    at com.intellij.psi.impl.source.tree.injected.InjectedPsiCachedValueProvider$MyInjProcessor.process(InjectedPsiCachedValueProvider.java:82)
    at com.intellij.psi.impl.source.tree.injected.InjectedLanguageManagerImpl.processInPlaceInjectorsFor(InjectedLanguageManagerImpl.java:446)
    at com.intellij.psi.impl.source.tree.injected.InjectedPsiCachedValueProvider.doCompute(InjectedPsiCachedValueProvider.java:62)
    at com.intellij.psi.impl.source.tree.injected.InjectedLanguageUtil.a(InjectedLanguageUtil.java:315)
    at com.intellij.psi.impl.source.tree.injected.InjectedLanguageUtil.enumerate(InjectedLanguageUtil.java:144)
    at com.intellij.psi.impl.source.tree.injected.InjectedLanguageUtil.enumerate(InjectedLanguageUtil.java:117)
    at com.intellij.psi.impl.source.tree.injected.InjectedLanguageManagerImpl.getInjectedPsiFiles(InjectedLanguageManagerImpl.java:459)
    at com.intellij.spring.model.values.PropertyValueConverter.getConverters(PropertyValueConverter.java:54)
    at com.intellij.util.xml.WrappingConverter.fromString(WrappingConverter.java:35)
    at com.intellij.util.xml.impl.GetInvocation.a(GetInvocation.java:102)
    at com.intellij.util.xml.impl.GetInvocation.a(GetInvocation.java:77)
    at com.intellij.util.xml.impl.GetInvocation.invoke(GetInvocation.java:65)
    at com.intellij.util.xml.impl.DomInvocationHandler.invoke(DomInvocationHandler.java:689)
    at com.intellij.util.xml.GenericAttributeValue$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$6007b85d.getValue()
    at com.intellij.spring.factories.resolvers.MethodInvokingFactoryBeanTypeResolver.getObjectType(MethodInvokingFactoryBeanTypeResolver.java:27)
    at com.intellij.spring.factories.SpringFactoryBeansManagerImpl.getProductTypeClassNames(SpringFactoryBeansManagerImpl.java:149)
    at com.intellij.spring.factories.SpringFactoryBeansManagerImpl.getProductTypes(SpringFactoryBeansManagerImpl.java:107)
    at com.intellij.spring.model.SpringFactoryBeansEffectiveTypesProviders.processEffectiveTypes(SpringFactoryBeansEffectiveTypesProviders.java:18)
    at com.intellij.spring.model.BeanServiceImpl.getEffectiveBeanTypes(BeanServiceImpl.java:40)
    at com.intellij.spring.model.SpringBaseBeanPointer$2.compute(SpringBaseBeanPointer.java:48)
    at com.intellij.psi.impl.PsiCachedValueImpl.doCompute(PsiCachedValueImpl.java:49)
    at com.intellij.util.CachedValueBase.getValueWithLock(CachedValueBase.java:200)
    at com.intellij.psi.impl.PsiCachedValueImpl.getValue(PsiCachedValueImpl.java:38)
    at com.intellij.spring.model.SpringBaseBeanPointer.getEffectiveBeanType(SpringBaseBeanPointer.java:53)
    at com.intellij.spring.model.converters.specific.MethodInvokingJobDetailFactoryBeanConverter.getPsiClass(MethodInvokingJobDetailFactoryBeanConverter.java:34)
    at com.intellij.spring.model.converters.PsiMethodConverter.fromString(PsiMethodConverter.java:70)
    at com.intellij.spring.model.converters.PsiMethodConverter.fromString(PsiMethodConverter.java:44)
    at com.intellij.util.xml.WrappingConverter.fromString(WrappingConverter.java:38)
    at com.intellij.util.xml.impl.GetInvocation.a(GetInvocation.java:102)
    at com.intellij.util.xml.impl.GetInvocation.a(GetInvocation.java:77)
    at com.intellij.util.xml.impl.GetInvocation.invoke(GetInvocation.java:65)
    at com.intellij.util.xml.impl.DomInvocationHandler.invoke(DomInvocationHandler.java:689)
    at com.intellij.util.xml.GenericAttributeValue$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$6007b85d.getValue()
    at com.intellij.spring.factories.resolvers.MethodInvokingFactoryBeanTypeResolver.getObjectType(MethodInvokingFactoryBeanTypeResolver.java:27)
    at com.intellij.spring.factories.SpringFactoryBeansManagerImpl.getProductTypeClassNames(SpringFactoryBeansManagerImpl.java:149)
    at com.intellij.spring.factories.SpringFactoryBeansManagerImpl.getProductTypes(SpringFactoryBeansManagerImpl.java:107)
    at com.intellij.spring.model.SpringFactoryBeansEffectiveTypesProviders.processEffectiveTypes(SpringFactoryBeansEffectiveTypesProviders.java:18)
    at com.intellij.spring.model.BeanServiceImpl.getEffectiveBeanTypes(BeanServiceImpl.java:40)
    at com.intellij.spring.model.SpringBaseBeanPointer$2.compute(SpringBaseBeanPointer.java:48)
    at com.intellij.psi.impl.PsiCachedValueImpl.doCompute(PsiCachedValueImpl.java:49)
    at com.intellij.util.CachedValueBase.getValueWithLock(CachedValueBase.java:200)
    at com.intellij.psi.impl.PsiCachedValueImpl.getValue(PsiCachedValueImpl.java:38)
    at com.intellij.spring.model.SpringBaseBeanPointer.getEffectiveBeanType(SpringBaseBeanPointer.java:53)
    at com.intellij.spring.model.converters.specific.MethodInvokingJobDetailFactoryBeanConverter.getPsiClass(MethodInvokingJobDetailFactoryBeanConverter.java:34)
    at com.intellij.spring.model.converters.PsiMethodConverter.fromString(PsiMethodConverter.java:70)
    at com.intellij.spring.model.converters.PsiMethodConverter.fromString(PsiMethodConverter.java:44)
    at com.intellij.util.xml.WrappingConverter.fromString(WrappingConverter.java:38)
    at com.intellij.util.xml.impl.GetInvocation.a(GetInvocation.java:102)
    at com.intellij.util.xml.impl.GetInvocation.a(GetInvocation.java:77)
    at com.intellij.util.xml.impl.GetInvocation.invoke(GetInvocation.java:65)
    at com.intellij.util.xml.impl.DomInvocationHandler.invoke(DomInvocationHandler.java:689)
    at com.intellij.util.xml.GenericAttributeValue$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$6007b85d.getValue()
    at com.intellij.spring.factories.resolvers.MethodInvokingFactoryBeanTypeResolver.getObjectType(MethodInvokingFactoryBeanTypeResolver.java:27)
    at com.intellij.spring.factories.SpringFactoryBeansManagerImpl.getProductTypeClassNames(SpringFactoryBeansManagerImpl.java:149)
    at com.intellij.spring.factories.SpringFactoryBeansManagerImpl.getProductTypes(SpringFactoryBeansManagerImpl.java:107)
    at com.intellij.spring.model.SpringFactoryBeansEffectiveTypesProviders.processEffectiveTypes(SpringFactoryBeansEffectiveTypesProviders.java:18)
    at com.intellij.spring.model.BeanServiceImpl.getEffectiveBeanTypes(BeanServiceImpl.java:40)
    at com.intellij.spring.model.SpringBaseBeanPointer$2.compute(SpringBaseBeanPointer.java:48)
    at com.intellij.psi.impl.PsiCachedValueImpl.doCompute(PsiCachedValueImpl.java:49)
    at com.intellij.util.CachedValueBase.getValueWithLock(CachedValueBase.java:200)
    at com.intellij.psi.impl.PsiCachedValueImpl.getValue(PsiCachedValueImpl.java:38)
    at com.intellij.spring.model.SpringBaseBeanPointer.getEffectiveBeanType(SpringBaseBeanPointer.java:53)
    at com.intellij.spring.model.converters.specific.MethodInvokingJobDetailFactoryBeanConverter.getPsiClass(MethodInvokingJobDetailFactoryBeanConverter.java:34)
    at com.intellij.spring.model.converters.PsiMethodConverter.fromString(PsiMethodConverter.java:70)
    at com.intellij.spring.model.converters.PsiMethodConverter.fromString(PsiMethodConverter.java:44)
    at com.intellij.util.xml.WrappingConverter.fromString(WrappingConverter.java:38)
    at com.intellij.util.xml.impl.GetInvocation.a(GetInvocation.java:102)
    at com.intellij.util.xml.impl.GetInvocation.a(GetInvocation.java:77)
    at com.intellij.util.xml.impl.GetInvocation.invoke(GetInvocation.java:65)
    at com.intellij.util.xml.impl.DomInvocationHandler.invoke(DomInvocationHandler.java:689)
    at com.intellij.util.xml.GenericAttributeValue$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$6007b85d.getValue()
    at com.intellij.spring.factories.resolvers.MethodInvokingFactoryBeanTypeResolver.getObjectType(MethodInvokingFactoryBeanTypeResolver.java:27)
    at com.intellij.spring.factories.SpringFactoryBeansManagerImpl.getProductTypeClassNames(SpringFactoryBeansManagerImpl.java:149)
    at com.intellij.spring.factories.SpringFactoryBeansManagerImpl.getProductTypes(SpringFactoryBeansManagerImpl.java:107)
...

Comment: did you try to increase the stack size e.g. `-Xss=4m`

Comment: You mean add `-Xss=4m` in idea64.exe.vmoptions? no that does not work since IDEA can not recognize this option and doesn't launch.

Answer (score 0):

First let's get this out of our way. The error is not coming because you are checking usage(Alt+ F7)
There are a couple of things taht can go wrong:

1. Intellij is running low on heap size. Please increase the heap size
   Go to Settings (Preferences on Mac) -> Compiler -> Java Compiler -> Maximum heap size (MB), and increase the size, then restart IntelliJ.
2. you are probably running 32 bit version of Intellij on 64 bit machine.

Comment: Let us know if the solution worked. In my case I was running 32 bit on a 64 bit machine and that was causing some memory issue.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. for 1, IdEA 14 has no > Compiler -> Java Compiler -> Maximum heap size (MB) option, and I think it's no help in my problem, because it's about compiler, not action. for 2, no, I'm running the 64 bit idea64.exe

Comment: @DineshArora the error is a stack overflow, not OutOfMemoryError (heap). There's an infinite loop here and it is happening as a result of invoking Find Usage, due to a circular code path between intellij's Spring and XML libraries.